# Why ActiveRecord automatically validates has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

Following models are given:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :answers
end

class Answers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: question
  validates :comment, presence: true
end
```

When calling

```
question = Question.new
question.answers.build
question.valid?
```

`valid?` returns `false` because the associated answer is not valid. When writing

```
has_many :answers, validate: false
```

in `Question` `valid?`returns `true`.

Is it a bug or is it desired when using `has_many` the associated models are validated automatically? The Rails Guides explicitly explain the use of `validate_associated` with a `has_many` relationship: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_associated

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it validate a model being created?

Comment: I create no model I only validate question. And why should a call to question.valid? triggers the validation of every answer although validate_associated is not explicitly set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's most definitely **not** a bug.

- You've created a `Question`
- You've told Rails to attach a new instance of `Answer` and relate it to this new `Question`
- You're then asking **"Rails, is this `Question/Answer` model and association I've created ready to be saved to the database?"**

As you've found, Rails will say **"No"** in your case.

I have never used and do not care about `validates_associated`. I can however point you to documentation explaining why you're seeing the behavior you are.

- **[Active Record Autosave Association](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb)**

Though the documentation at the above source file is worth reading in it's entirety, I'll pull out this bit for you

> Note that :autosave => false is not same as not declaring :autosave.
>     **When the :autosave option is not present new associations are saved.**

- You have not specified `:autosave => SOMETHING` on your `:answers` association
- Because of this, Rails by default is going to try and save your newly build/associated `Answer` on your new `Question`
- The save will fail because the `Answer` is invalid

Comment: I dont try to save quesiton I only call valid? on question thus autosave is not what I want. When having a have_one association valid? isn't called automatically on the associated record. Why have_many differes here. I don't want to rely on a behavior which could be bug and fixed in the next version.

Comment: `save` calls `valid` as part of its process. set `:autosave => false` on the association if you're trying to avoid this behavior. There's not much more I can do except tell you it's not a bug, point to the documentation explaining the reasoning and behavior, and bump you in the right direction towards "fixing" the problem you are having if you choose to make a change.

Comment: This comment in the autosave_association.rb explains the behavior _"Children records are validated unless <tt>:validate</tt> is +false+."_ But it's very strange that it is not applied on has_one, so there is a least a big inconsistency or maybe a bug. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have overriden `valid?` in parent model in order to handle the validation taking care also their nested associations' status:

```
def valid?(context=nil)
  super(context) && self.answers.map(&:valid?).all?
end
```